# Getting shipping costs in cart without address?

Tags: shipping, shipping-address

If the user puts an item to the cart, Magento shows no shipping costs, because it doesnt know the shipping address yet. I searched the code, where it tries to find the address, but could not find it. I want to set a shipping address in Germany if there is no address specified yet. Any idea in what part of the code I have to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: There are a few blog articles, which descripe this, like http://www.danneh.org/2010/08/adding-shipping-costs-to-the-cart-automatically-in-magento/

Answer (score 0):

Agree this is covered by article Fabian points to - http://www.danneh.org/2010/08/adding-shipping-costs-to-the-cart-automatically-in-magento/

Comment: any article related to magento 2?